# calendar program assistance necessary in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, calendar

Here is my calendar program as you can see below:

```
public class calendar
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        new calendar ();
    }


    public calendar ()
    {
    int day = IBIO.inputInt ("Enter day: ");
    int numOfDays = IBIO.inputInt ("Enter the number of days in the month: ");

    System.out.println ("S  M  T  W  T  F  S");
    if (day==1)
     {
      for (int i=1; i<=7; i++)
       {
        System.out.print (i + "  ");
       }
       }
    else if (day==2)
     {
      System.out.print ("   ");
      for (int i = 1; i <=6; i++)
      {
       System.out.print (i+"  ");
      }
      }
    else if (day==3)
     {
      System.out.print ("      ");
      for (int i = 1; i <=5; i++)
      {
       System.out.print (i+"  ");
      }
      }
    else if (day==4)
     {
      System.out.print ("         ");
      for (int i = 1; i <=4; i++)
      {
       System.out.print (i+ "  ");
      }
      }
    else if (day==5)
     {
      System.out.print ("            ");
      for (int i = 1; i <=3; i++)
      {    
       System.out.print (i+"  ");
      }
      }
    else if (day==6)
     {
      System.out.print ("               ");
      for (int i = 1; i <=1; i++)
     {
      System.out.print (i + "  ");
     }
     }
    else
     {
      System.out.print ("                  ");
      for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++)
      {
       System.out.print (i+ "  ");
      }
     }
    }
   }
```

Now what I want to do is expand on to this program since only the first row gets outputted. I want the entire month to get outputted and this must correspond to the number of days that the user inputs through the variable `numOfDays`. By the way, `IBIO.input` is how the user stores input.

Comment: Have you noticed a pattern in your code that you could perhaps simplify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is really complicated. I don't think mine is the best either, but here it is:

```
public calendar() {
    int day = 2;
    int numOfDays = 28;

    System.out.println("S  M  T  W  T  F  S");
    for(int i = 1; i < day; i++){
        System.out.print("   ");
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= numOfDays; i++){
        System.out.print(addSpaces(i + "", 3));
        if((i + day - 1) % 7 == 0){
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}

public String addSpaces(String s, int length){
    while(s.length() < length){
        s+= " ";
    }
    return s;
}
```

Try to understand this, it first prints some spaces to skip the first days, then it prints out all days and every seventh day, it begins a new line.

The output is:

```
S  M  T  W  T  F  S
   1  2  3  4  5  6  
7  8  9  10 11 12 13 
14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
28
```

Comment: This works, thank you :)

Comment: No problem, I'm on holiday and really bored ^^

Comment: Can you help me fix my nim program as well?

Comment: sorry, I don't know nim at all. If the problem is a logical one, I could try it, but I don't know anything about the syntax.

Comment: it's a game in java lol. I'm just having a problem with the name variable in my code.

Comment: Oh, i didn't knew what nim stands for, so I googled it and found a programming language ^^

Comment: LOL here is the link to my other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105228/need-to-fix-the-name-parameter-variable-in-nim-program-java?noredirect=1#comment59853152_36105228

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you are trying to print a calendar by taking the number of days and the starting day as input from the user.

With the logic you have written it will only print the first row as there is no `loop` or `recursion`. What you should be doing instead is printing all the rows by using a `loop`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public class calendar
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        new calendar ();
    }

    public calendar ()
    {
        int day = IBIO.inputInt ("Enter Day (Number): ");
        int numOfDays = IBIO.inputInt ("Enter the number of days in the month: ");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        System.out.println("S  M  T  W  T  F  S");
        char[] spaces = new char[(day - 1) * 3];
        Arrays.fill(spaces,' ');

        sb.append(spaces);      
        for(int i = 1; i <= numOfDays; i++) {
            if(sb.length() > 19) {
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
                sb = new StringBuilder();
            }

            sb.append(i);
            if(i / 10 < 1) {
                sb.append("  ");
            } else {
                sb.append(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Input:

```
Enter Day (Number): 2
Enter the number of days in the month: 31
```

Output:

```
S  M  T  W  T  F  S
   1  2  3  4  5  6  
7  8  9  10 11 12 13 
14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
28 29 30 31
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variant.

```
static void cal( int day, int numOfDays ){
    System.out.println(" S  M  T  W  T  F  S");
    for( int d = 2 - day; d <= numOfDays; ++d ){
        System.out.print( (d <= 0 ? "  " : d <= 9 ? " " + d : d)
                          + " " );
        if( d%7 == (8-day)%7 ) System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The idea is somewhat gonzo: extend the days of the month into the non-positives to avoid the initial indentation. Counting the printed positions and triggering println on that avoids the tricky condition with two modulo operations.

(It's not good coding practice to do such things in a constructor.)